# Populate sql column from query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

**requests**

**requests_votes**

request structure is:

```
id | req_name | content | hits
------------------------------
1  | Sample   | Some    | NULL
2  | Sample   | Some    | NULL
3  | Sample   | Some    | NULL
4  | Sample   | Some    | NULL
5  | Sample   | Some    | NULL
```

requests_votes structure is:

```
id | requestid | user_id
------------------------
10 | 2         | 2556
18 | 2         | 2522
33 | 3         | 120
44 | 2         | 1559
98 | 5         | 253
```

width the following query im able to calculate how votes have an item(request)

```
SELECT `requestid` , count( requests_votes.id ) AS totals
FROM `requests_votes`
INNER JOIN `requests` ON requests.id = requests_votes.requestid
GROUP BY `requestid`
```

output:

```
requestid | totals
------------------
2         | 3
3         | 1
5         | 1
```

i want to populate the **hits** column inside requests table with **count( requests_votes.id )** result.

I've go trough the similar questions asked here on stackoverflow, but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Do you want to update the column? Or you want to create a view and no need for the hits column?

Comment: Ive added the hits column and i want to update it with the results of: count( requests_votes.id ) AS totals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE `requests` T1 JOIN
  (SELECT `requestid` , count( requests_votes.id ) AS totals
   FROM `requests_votes`
   INNER JOIN `requests` ON requests.id = requests_votes.requestid
   GROUP BY `requestid`) T2 ON T1.id=T2.requestid
SET T1.hits=T2.totals
```

Comment: it returns:
#1054 - Unknown column 'T1.requestid' in 'on clause'

Comment: @V.Donchev: Just fixed it. Try it now.